# Laravel Yajra DataTable search with enter key or search with a length or search with button

Tags: laravel, search, datatable, yajra-datatable, laravel-datatables

I have a Laravel application which uses yajra datatable, and it searches every time, when text entered, which makes searching very slow.

Below is the code which I have tried.
I want to try with searchable() method which accepts boolean true/false to search only a specific characters. but i don't know how to get search input length from datatable

```
  <?php

namespace App\DataTables;

use App\Models\Currency;
use App\Models\instantTrip;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Button;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Column;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Editor\Editor;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Editor\Fields;
use Yajra\DataTables\Services\DataTable;

class instantTripsDataTable extends DataTable
{
    /**
     * Build DataTable class.
     *
     * @param mixed $query Results from query() method.
     * @return \Yajra\DataTables\DataTableAbstract
     */
    protected $filter_type;

    // Set the Type of Filter applied to Payout
    public function setFilter($filter_type)
    {
        $this->filter_type = $filter_type;
        return $this;
    }
    public function dataTable($query)
    {
        return datatables()
            ->of($query)
            ->addColumn('action', function ($trips) {
                $edit = '<a href="'.url(LOGIN_USER_TYPE.'/view_trips/'.$trips->id).'" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>';

                return $edit;
            });
    }

    /**
     * Get query source of dataTable.
     *
     * @param Trips $model
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function query()
    {

        $default_currency = Currency::active()->defaultCurrency()->first();
        if (LOGIN_USER_TYPE=='company' && session()->get('currency') != null) {  //if login user is company then get session currency
            $default_currency = Currency::whereCode(session()->get('currency'))->first();
        }
        $symbol = $default_currency->symbol;
        $currency_rate = $default_currency->rate;

        $trips =  DB::table('trips')->join('users as rider', function($join) {
            $join->on('rider.id', '=', 'trips.user_id');
        })
            ->join('currency', function($join) {
                $join->on('currency.code', '=', 'trips.currency_code');
            })
            ->join('car_type', function($join) {
                $join->on('car_type.id', '=', 'trips.car_id');
            })
            ->join('users as driver', function($join) {
                $join->on('driver.id', '=', 'trips.driver_id');

                //If login user is company then get that company drivers only
                if (LOGIN_USER_TYPE=='company') {
                    $join->where('driver.company_id',auth('company')->user()->id);
                }
                if (LOGIN_USER_TYPE=='corporate') {
                    $join->where('rider.corporate_id',auth('corporate')->user()->id);
                }


            })
            ->join('companies', function($join) {
                $join->on('driver.company_id', '=', 'companies.id');
            })
            ->select(['trips.id as id','rider.mobile_number as rider_mobile_number','driver.mobile_number as mobile_number','driver.first_name as driver_name','rider.first_name as rider_name','trips.pickup_location as pickup_location','trips.drop_location as drop_location','trips.created_at as trip_date','car_type.car_name as car_name','trips.status as status','companies.name as company_name',
                DB::raw('concat("'.$symbol.'", if ("'.LOGIN_USER_TYPE.'"="company", ( 
                        sum(ROUND((trips.subtotal_fare / currency.rate) * '.$currency_rate.',2)) 
                        + sum(ROUND((trips.driver_peak_amount / currency.rate) * '.$currency_rate.',2)) 
                        + sum(ROUND((trips.tips / currency.rate) * '.$currency_rate.',2)) 
                        + sum(ROUND((trips.waiting_charge / currency.rate) * '.$currency_rate.',2)) 
                        + sum(ROUND((trips.toll_fee / currency.rate) * '.$currency_rate.',2))
                        - sum(ROUND((trips.driver_or_company_commission / currency.rate) * '.$currency_rate.',2))
                        + sum(ROUND((trips.additional_rider_amount / currency.rate) * '.$currency_rate.',2))  ) 
                        ,
                        (
                        sum(ROUND((trips.subtotal_fare / currency.rate) * '.$currency_rate.',2)) 
                        + sum(ROUND((trips.peak_amount / currency.rate) * '.$currency_rate.',2)) 
                        + sum(ROUND((trips.access_fee / currency.rate) * '.$currency_rate.',2)) 
                        + sum(ROUND((trips.schedule_fare / currency.rate) * '.$currency_rate.',2)) 
                        + sum(ROUND(( if((trips.payment_status="Completed"),(trips.tips / currency.rate),0 ) * '.$currency_rate.'),2))
                        - sum(ROUND((trips.toll_fee / currency.rate) * '.$currency_rate.',2))
                        + sum(ROUND((trips.waiting_charge / currency.rate) * '.$currency_rate.',2))  ))) as total_amount '),


            ])->where('trips.isInstatnt','1');
        if($this->filter_type == 'today') {
            $trips->whereDate('trips.created_at', '=', date('Y-m-d'));
        }
        $trips->groupBy('trips.id');
        return $trips;
    }

    /**
     * Optional method if you want to use html builder.
     *
     * @return \Yajra\DataTables\Html\Builder
     */
    public function html()
    {
        return $this->builder()
            ->columns($this->getColumns())
            ->minifiedAjax()
            ->dom('lBfr<"table-responsive"t>ip')
            ->orderBy(0)
            ->buttons(
                ['csv', 'excel', 'print', 'reset']
            );
    }

    /**
     * Get columns.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getColumns()
    {
        $col_list_1 = [
            ['data' => 'id', 'name' => 'trips.id', 'title' => 'Id'],
            ['data' => 'driver_name', 'name' => 'driver.first_name', 'title' => 'Driver Name'],
            ['data' => 'mobile_number', 'name' => 'driver.mobile_number', 'title' => 'Driver Mobile Number'],
            ['data' => 'rider_mobile_number', 'name' => 'rider.mobile_number', 'title' => 'Rider Mobile Number'],

            ['data' => 'rider_name', 'name' => 'rider.first_name', 'title' => 'Rider Name'],
        ];

        $col_list_2 = [
            ['data' => 'pickup_location', 'name' => 'trips.pickup_location', 'title' => 'Pickup Location'],
            ['data' => 'drop_location', 'name' => 'trips.drop_location', 'title' => 'Drop Location'],
            ['data' => 'trip_date', 'name' => 'trips.created_at', 'title' => 'Trip Date'],
        ];

        $col_list_3 = [
            ['data' => 'car_name', 'name' => 'car_type.car_name', 'title' => 'Vehicle Details'],
            ['data' => 'status', 'name' => 'trips.status', 'title' => 'Status'],
            ['data' => 'action', 'name' => 'action', 'title' => 'Action', 'orderable' => false, 'searchable' => false, 'exportable' => false],
        ];

        if(LOGIN_USER_TYPE == 'company') {
            $payout_columns = array(
                ['data' => 'total_amount', 'name' => 'total_fare', 'title' => 'Earned'],
            );
            $company_columns = array();
        }
        else {
            $payout_columns = array(
                ['data' => 'total_amount', 'name' => 'total_fare', 'title' => 'Earned'],
            );
            $company_columns = array(
                ['data' => 'company_name', 'name' => 'companies.name', 'title' => 'Company Name']
            );
        }

        return array_merge($col_list_1,$payout_columns,$col_list_2,$company_columns,$col_list_3);
    }

    /**
     * Get filename for export.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function filename()
    {
        return 'instantTrips_' . date('YmdHis');
    }
}
```

I want to search when enter key is pressed (or) search starts only after a certain character